# Understanding $E(1_{[X>n]}) = P[X>n]$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm checking some notes in measure and integration theory, and found this statement:

$E(1_{[X>n]}) = P[X>n]$

Just need to understand it.

Is this the correct interpretation? Please need some advise.

I think  $E(1_{[X>n]}) = \int_{X>n} dP  $.

But I'm not able to link this integral to  $P[X>n]$.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you what is the density of a probability measure, in terms of its relation to Lebesgue measure? Radon Nikodym derivative?

Comment: Sorry, have no idea about Radon Nikodym derivative.  Assume this is a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{B},\mathbb{P})$, and that $X$ is a non-negative random variable. I think, since this is a RV, we can assume this is Lebesgue measure.

Comment: The only way this could be confusing you is if you didn't know what the integral of a simple function is.

Comment: What is your definition for $\mathbb{P}(X>n)$?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, specially @DionelJaime's, very constructive and helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write out the expectation:

$$\int 1_{X>n} dP_X = \int_{X\leq n} 1_{X>n} dP_X + \int_{X>n} 1_{X>n} dP_X =  \int_{X\leq n} 0\; dP_X + \int_{X>n} 1 dP_X = P_X((n,\infty))$$

You see that you are only integrating over the set where $X>n$, the rest of the domain of the probability measure is zeroed out by the indicator function.

Comment: Thanks. Great answer, clear and neat. Maybe this was a silly question, but you really helped me understanding. Thanks!

Comment: @htennek2k no problem...even simple things can be hard when you're first learning the subject and notation.

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate your help. I'm indeed learning this stuff and getting used to the notation.